# clickable fa-heart-o fontawsome not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

The below code create a no filled heart and it must filled by user click, but this code not working for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select:none ;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: darkblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the icon to toggle between heart </p>

<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-heart");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But if change the

```
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
...
x.classList.toggle("fa-heart");
```

to this

```
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-heart"></i>
...
x.classList.toggle("fa-heart-o");
```

it worked.
I want to show first `fa-heart-o` and after user click it filled and changed to `fa-heart`

Comment: Since you are technically toggling two classes (fa-heart and fa-heart-o) you might want to use an if statement instead of a stand alone toggle

Comment: please make a demo fiddle

Comment: What Font Awesome version are you using? As of the current version, there is no `fa-heart-o` class, but the full/empty version have `far` or `fas` class prepending. And, as other have mentioned, toggleClass will **switch** the class you pass as argument on/off, if you want to switch between different classes you need either an if-else statement or two toggleClass

Comment: with if-else same result, the version of Font awesome is 4.

Comment: @Tofiq post your if-else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClassList toggling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is really only intended to be used when you're working with a single class. When toggling, if the specified class exists then it will be removed, otherwise it will be added. Currently your element will always have the `fa-heart-o` class, and you're trying to add the `fa-heart` class to override it.

In FontAwesome the `fa-heart-o` class is defined *after* the `fa-heart` class. Therefore `fa-heart-o` will always override `fa-heart` since, otherwise, they have the same specificity. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more information.

In your case, rather than toggling a single class you need to remove one class and add the other.

Your script might look like this:

```
function myFunction(x) {
    if ( x.classList.contains( "fa-heart") ) {
        x.classList.remove( "fa-heart" );
        x.classList.add( "fa-heart-o" );
    }
    else {
        x.classList.remove( "fa-heart-o" );
        x.classList.add( "fa-heart" );
    }
}
```

Comment: thkx, this exactly what I want. But one question why my code worked for(fa-heart to fa-heart-o) but vice versa not working?

Comment: @Tofiq in the FontAwesome stylesheet `fa-heart-o` is defined after `fa-heart`, therefore it overrides `fa-heart`'s definitions. Eg when you started with just `fa-heart` and then toggled `fa-heart-o` on, the element would have both `fa-heart` and `fa-heart-o` classes. Since the `fa-heart-o` class overrides `fa-heart` you would get an open heart. When you started with `fa-heart-o` and added `fa-heart`, nothing would appear to change as you would again have both classes applied to the same element and the newly added `fa-heart` class would be overridden by the original `fa-heart-o` class.